# No tests were found (doctest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest, doctest

Getting pretty fed up with PyCharm here. I'm following a Pluralsight module and I can't get the doctest to work. It says "No tests were found" despite having properly formatted docstring. My Configurations are correct and oddly enough, it works in the terminal but not when I run it.

```
def small_straight(dice):
    """Score the given roll in the 'small straight' yatzy category.

    >>> small_straight([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    15
    >>> small_straight([1, 2, 3, 3, 5])
    0

    It doesn't handle sets, or unsorted lists

    >>> small_straight({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
    0
    >>> small_straight([1, 2, 3, 5, 4])
    0
    """
    if dice == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        return sum(dice)
    return 0
```

Comment: So how are you running the doctests? It works fine for me if I run "Run 'doctests in...'" in the file context menu in PyCharm.

Comment: I figured it out... MY configuration was off by 1 folder. I was staring at it for 30min, walked away for lunch, came back and notice it immediately.

Comment: So no need to blame PyCharm :)